Issues serving static image files after deployment to Vercel

api/vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    { 
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node" 
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ] 
}

api/index.js
const __dirname = path.resolve();

app.use(
  "/images/products",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images", "products")),
);

I am trying to deploy the mern app to vercel with react website serving static images from backend but when after deployed the backend the other routes can work as usual while the image routes like https://deployed-web-api.vercel.app/images/products/product-1.png cannot read the image, however, http://localhost:4000/images/products/product-1.png could load the image. I tried to figure out the problems and tried to change the code with different solutions but still could not work
Before asking I tried to find out different solutions from other questions and took reference to try to apply on my code but still not working

"the other routes can work as usual"... do you have an example of what those other routes look like?

I mean like app.use("/api/v1/auth", authRoutes) inside those controllers are working as usual

I don't know Vercel very well but perhaps that /api prefix is significant since it matches your directory name

Or instead I should use api to render the images?

I'd hazard a guess that if you used /api/images/products, it would start working

After I changed to app.use("/api/images/products", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images", "products"))) and access https://clicon-web-api.vercel.app/api/images/products/product-2.png the message still shows that route not exist could not load image

I found many posts that had the same issue but still could not help
